# How to define default welcome page in an equinox OSGI server?

Tags: java, servlets, osgi

We are using OSGI Equinox "org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.resources" extension to define resources accessible in our different JAR in our OSGI Equinox server. Most of them are just to point to static HTML content so there's no Servlet implementation. I was wondering what was the easiest way to define the default page for a sub folder (defining the "Welcome" file usually defined in a web.xml in standard Servlet packaging). Basically, I define a resource at /mynewresource and would link the user to be directed to index.html when he enters  instead of getting a server error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to have a default behavior of going to index.html on your resource, you can create that simple filter:

```
public class WelcomFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter {

/** {@inheritDoc} */
@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

}

/** {@inheritDoc} */
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
        HttpServletRequest r = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        if ("/".equals(r.getPathInfo())) {
            r.getRequestDispatcher("index.html").forward(request, response);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}

/** {@inheritDoc} */
@Override
public void destroy() {

}
}
```

You have two choices: you can register this filter once at the root (/) but keep in mind that any request with no path info will get redirected to index.html or you can register it for the sub-domain where you want it. In any case, you need to use the equinox http filter extension.

```
    <extension
         point="org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.filters">
      <filter
            alias="/mydomain"
            class="com.abc.filters.WelcomeFilter">
      </filter>
   </extension>
```

Comment: Filters is not in the current specification, so you're tying your implementation to a particular implementation of the HTTP Service. There is an ongoing effort to add support for filters in the next version of the HTTP Service specification.

Comment: which xml file are you suggesting adding the `<extension>` xml to?

Comment: @pstanton You need to add that in your plugin.xml

Answer (score 0):

There is no standardised way *yet* to define a default (or welcome) page in an OSGi server.

Coincidentally, I faced the same and decided to add this functionality to the [Amdatu-Web](https://bitbucket.org/amdatu/amdatu-web) project. Aside allowing non-Java resources to be served through the web, it now also allows you to define a default page like:

```
X-Web-Resource-Default-Page: index.html
```

or a default page for a specific directory:

```
X-Web-Resource-Default-Page: /path=index.html
```

The default page(s) will be served in case no file is requested.

It is not entirely done yet, as it needs some reviewing and I need to update the documentation and examples a bit on the Amdatu website. But, you can already take a look at the code (especially the demo project in the BitBucket project) to get an idea of how it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I was afraid there was no standard way. This should definitely be add soon in OSGI server, it is such a basic and needed feature!

Answer (score 0):

Filters didn't work for me (using Kura/Equinox) however, using a custom HttpContext implementation I was able to add the required logic in `getResources`.